# How to move data from one SQLite to MySQL with different designs?

Tags: mysql, database, sqlite, web, migration

The problem is:
I've got a SQLite database which is constantly being updated though a proprietary application.

I'm building an application which uses MySQL and the database design is very different from the one of SQLite.

I then have to copy data from SQLite to MySQL but it should be done very carefully as not everything should be moved, tables and fields have different names and sometimes data from one table goes to two tables (or the opposite).

In short, SQLite should behave as a client to MySQL inserting what is new and updating the old in an automated way. It doesn't need to be updating in real time; every X hours would be enough.

A google search gave me this:
http://migratedb.sourceforge.net/

And asking a friend I got information about the Multisource plugin (Squirrel SQL) in this page:
http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/index.php?page=plugins

I would like to know if there is a better way to solve the problem or if I will have to make a custom script myself.

Thank you!

Comment: A [list of converters](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ConverterTools) fro different platforms. Personally, I'd vote for custom script.

Comment: +1 to custom script. If you are comfortable with SQLite and MySQL APIs in any one language, then querying the first and writing to the second can be done by you with your own rules for conversion/translation.

Comment: Forgot to add: There will also be manual inserts and updates. The solutions must not erase or modify what has been added manually.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend a custom script for this:

1. If it's not a one-to-one conversion between the tables and fields, tools might not help there. In your question, you've said:

   > ...and sometimes data from one table goes to two tables (or the opposite).
2. If you only want the differences, then you'll need to build the logic for that unless every record in the SQLite db has timestamps.
3. Are you going to be updating the MySQL db at all? If not, are you okay to completely delete the MySQL db and refresh it every X hours with all the data from SQLite?

Also, if you are **comfortable with a scripting language (like php, python, perl, ruby, etc.)**, they have API's for both SQLite and MySQL; it would be easy enough to build your own script which you can control customise more easily based on program logic. Especially if you want to run "conversions" between the data from one to the other and not just simple mapping.

Answer (score 0):

I hope i understand you correctly, that you will flush the data which are stored in a SQLite DB periodicly to a MySQL DB. Right?

**So this is how i would do it.**

1. Create a Cron, which starts the script every x minutes.
2. Export the Data from SQLite into an CSV-File.
3. Do an `LOAD DATA INFILE` an import the CSV Data to MySQL

**Code example for `LOAD DATA INFILE`**

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'PATH_TO_EXPORTED_CSV' REPLACE INTO TABLE your_table FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n' IGNORE 1 LINES ( @value_column1, @unimportend_value, @value_column2, @unimportend_value, @unimportend_value, @value_column3) SET diff_mysql_column1 = @value_column1, diff_mysql_column2 = @value_column2, diff_mysql_column3 = @value_column3);
```

This Code you can query to as much db tables you want. Also you can change the variables `@value_column1`.
Im in a hurry. so thats it for now. ask if something is unclear.
Greets  Michael